# Reverse complement of DNA strand using Python

Tags: python, list, bioinformatics, biopython, dna-sequence

I have a DNA sequence and would like to get reverse complement of it using Python. It is in one of the columns of a CSV file and I'd like to write the reverse complement to another column in the same file. The tricky part is, there are a few cells with something other than A, T, G and C. I was able to get reverse complement with this piece of code:

```
def complement(seq):
    complement = {'A': 'T', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A'} 
    bases = list(seq) 
    bases = [complement[base] for base in bases] 
    return ''.join(bases)
    def reverse_complement(s):
        return complement(s[::-1])

    print "Reverse Complement:"
    print(reverse_complement("TCGGGCCC"))
```

However, when I try to find the item which is not present in the complement dictionary, using the code below, I just get the complement of the last base. It doesn't iterate. I'd like to know how I can fix it.

```
def complement(seq):
    complement = {'A': 'T', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A'} 
    bases = list(seq) 
    for element in bases:
        if element not in complement:
            print element  
        letters = [complement[base] for base in element] 
        return ''.join(letters)
def reverse_complement(seq):
    return complement(seq[::-1])

print "Reverse Complement:"
print(reverse_complement("TCGGGCCCCX"))
```

Comment: What do you want to be the complement of items not present in the dictionary? The original item itself?

Comment: Your `return` in `complement` is incorrectly indented.

Comment: @aa333 There are some values like ins and dup, I'd like to print them as it is. I've tried using Bio.Seq but it converts 'ins' to 'sni' while reverse complementing.

Comment: first replace `ins` and other "bases" with single letter substitutes, reverse, then put them back

Comment: @Gabriel is there a Pythonic way to do that, since I'm afraid I can't do it manually. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `get` method of a dictionary allows you to specify a default value if the key is not in the dictionary. As a preconditioning step I would map all your non 'ATGC' bases to single letters (or punctuation or numbers or anything that wont show up in your sequence), then reverse the sequence, then replace the single letter alternates with their originals.  Alternatively, you could reverse it first and then search and replace things like `sni` with `ins`.

```
alt_map = {'ins':'0'}
complement = {'A': 'T', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A'} 

def reverse_complement(seq):    
    for k,v in alt_map.iteritems():
        seq = seq.replace(k,v)
    bases = list(seq) 
    bases = reversed([complement.get(base,base) for base in bases])
    bases = ''.join(bases)
    for k,v in alt_map.iteritems():
        bases = bases.replace(v,k)
    return bases

>>> seq = "TCGGinsGCCC"
>>> print "Reverse Complement:"
>>> print(reverse_complement(seq))
GGGCinsCCGA
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I cannot hard code the element 'alt' because it can be anything. There's no definite structure for it.

Comment: updated the answer to work w/o knowing what the the other bases will be

Comment: Just use `complement.get(base,base)`.

Comment: If you want to publish this somewhere, beware [Ambiguity codes](http://reverse-complement.com/ambiguity.html)

Comment: A fastest and clearer way to reverse a string: `your_string[::-1]`

Answer (score 40):

The other answers are perfectly fine, but if you plan to deal with real DNA sequences I suggest using [Biopython](http://www.biopython.org). What if you encounter a character like "-", "*" or indefinitions? What if you want to do further manipulations of your sequences? Do you want to create a parser for each file format out there?

The code you ask for is as easy as:

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq

seq = Seq("TCGGGCCC")

print seq.reverse_complement()
# GGGCCCGA
```

Now if you want to do another transformations:

```
print seq.complement()
print seq.transcribe()
print seq.translate()
```

Outputs

```
AGCCCGGG
UCGGGCCC
SG
```

And if you run into strange chars, no need to keep adding code to your program. Biopython deals with it:

```
seq = Seq("TCGGGCCCX")
print seq.reverse_complement()
# XGGGCCCGA
```

Answer (score 20):

In general, a generator expression is simpler than the original code and avoids creating extra list objects. If there can be multiple-character insertions go with the other answers.

```
complement = {'A': 'T', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A'}
seq = "TCGGGCCC"
reverse_complement = "".join(complement.get(base, base) for base in reversed(seq))
```

Comment: why do you need `(base, base)` two times here?

Comment: @IgorBarinov: The `get` function has a default return type of `None` for when the key is not available. Setting `base` as the default return type avoids a `KeyError` and just inserts the value for `base`. The effect is that unusual characters in the sequence are now handled (correctly).

Answer (score 16):

```
import string
old_chars = "ACGT"
replace_chars = "TGCA"
tab = string.maketrans(old_chars,replace_chars)
print "AAAACCCGGT".translate(tab)[::-1]
```

that will give you the reverse compliment = ACCGGGTTTT

Comment: Best answer for me. Note it needs to be adapted for python3: replace `string` by `str` (no need to import) and obviously add parentheses to `print`.

Comment: answered Oct 28 '14 at 18:35 - At the time that was correct ... yes, you are right. Great observation.

Answer (score 4):

The fastest one liner for reverse complement is the following:

```
def rev_compl(st):
    nn = {'A': 'T', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A'}
    return "".join(nn[n] for n in reversed(st))
```

Comment: Best answer, for pure Python

Answer (score 2):

```
def ReverseComplement(Pattern):
    revcomp = []
    x = len(Pattern)
    for i in Pattern:
        x = x - 1
        revcomp.append(Pattern[x])
    return ''.join(revcomp)

# this if for the compliment 

def compliment(Nucleotide):
    comp = []
    for i in Nucleotide:
        if i == "T":
            comp.append("A")
        if i == "A":
            comp.append("T")
        if i == "G":
            comp.append("C")
        if i == "C":
            comp.append("G")

    return ''.join(comp)
```

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to below code,

```
complement = {'A': 'T', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A'}
seq = "TCGGGCCC"
reverse_complement = "".join(complement.get(base, base) for base in reversed(seq))
```

Comment: Add code formatting to your post. Also, consider adding any explanation to your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Considering also degenerate bases:

```
def rev_compl(seq):
    BASES ='NRWSMBDACGTHVKSWY'
    return ''.join([BASES[-j] for j in [BASES.index(i) for i in seq][::-1]])
```

Comment: Please note that `str.find()` is very dangerous in this case, because any base not in `BASES` will return `j` as `-1` (and `BASES[-j]` as `R`). Please use `str.index()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `timeit` module for speed profiling, this is the fastest algorithm I came up with with my coworkers for sequences < 200 nucs:

```
sequence \
    .replace('A', '*') \  # Temporary symbol
    .replace('T', 'A') \
    .replace('*', 'T') \
    .replace('C', '&') \  # Temporary symbol
    .replace('G', 'C') \
    .replace('&', 'G')[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be the quickest way to complete a reverse compliment:

```
def complement(seq):
    complementary = { 'A':'T', 'T':'A', 'G':'C','C':'G' }
    return ''.join(reversed([complementary[i] for i in seq]))
```