# How would I write a program in python that uses Custom Function to return the reverse complement of a DNA seq in the 5' to 3' orientation?

Tags: python

That is, if given the sequence GGCCAATT, the program would return AATTGGCC?
And the program must also work regardless of whitespace (spaces or tabs), case, and line breaks.

Comment: I think this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188968/reverse-complement-of-dna-strand-using-python) answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sequence is a string `replace` should do the trick:

```py
sequence = 'GGCCAATT'
swap_A_G = sequence.replace('G', 'X').replace('A', 'G').replace('X', 'A')
swap_T_C = swap_A_G.replace('T', 'X').replace('C', 'T').replace('X', 'C')
```

It's ugly, but stringmethods are pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

my_dna='G    g \t C   cA\n   A t    T'

def my_func(dna_seq):
    Output=(re.sub('\s*','', dna_seq)[4:]+re.sub('\s*','', dna_seq)[:4]).upper()
    return Output
```

my_dna:

```
print(my_dna)

G    g   C   cA
   A t    T
```

Output:

```
my_func(my_dna)

'AATTGGCC'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to deal with dna sequencing Biopython is a module in python you are searching for.
you can easily get the reverse complement as follows.

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq

seq=Seq('GGCCAATT')
dna=seq.reverse_complement()
print(dna)//AATTGGCC
```